# numbers , and operations with ()

Tags: c, operation, integer-arithmetic

So I got a problem with my logic with operators in C . I don't know how the compiler run those (%)/?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
int number1=1606,number2,number3,number4;
number2 = number1/5000;
number3 = (number1%5000)/1000;
number4 = (number1%5000)%1000/100;
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d",number1,number2,number3,number4);
return 0;
}
```

So i don't understand that number3?
Isn't 1606%5000 = 3212 and then / 1000 = 3 ? So i get 1 from that how its working ?

Comment: `%` is the modulus operator (i.e. remainder from division).  How are you getting 1606%5000 = 3212?

Comment: and what's `number`, you declared only `number1,...`

Comment: 1606/5000 = 0.3212 ?

Comment: Sorry my bad i fix it that number into number1

Comment: @World: .`%` is the modulus operator, not division - the result is the *remainder* of 1606/5000, which is...1606.  Thus 1606/1000 is 1.

Comment: Its ok i get it .. my bad i don't understand how that % works but now its ok ty to everyone :) <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement

```
number3 = (number1%5000)/1000;
```

there is used integer arithmetic. The operator % yields the remainder of the operation /.

So the sub-expression `number1%5000` gives the value `1606` because

number1 can be represented like

```
number1 = 0 * 5000 + 1606.
```

Dividing the remainder by `1000` you will get `1`.

From the C Standard (6.5.5 Multiplicative operators)

> 5 The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of
>   the first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the
>   remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undefined.